# How to make a dashboard/visualize XML Data?

Tags: xml, powershell, dashboard, xml-visualizer

I created a powershell script that pulls SNMP data from devices, and creates pscustomobjects with attributes of the data, and outputs them as separate objects in an array that I then export as an XML data file. The file itself looks clean and neat, easily separated. My question is how do I visualize this in a dashboard? Don't mind making it myself, just unaware of the standard tools or scripting languages to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question to provide more details, such as sample XML and its desired visualization. If you're looking for an HTML-based visualization, an XSLT transformation is an obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have XML output, might I recommend Power BI!
[Power Query XML editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/xml)
You can import the XML to Power BI Desktop and visualise that way, with lots of free content available at Microsoft's Learn site.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for but the application is less than stellar.. it's handling of charts and visualization is really bad. I ended up converting the data to HTML and embedding a CSS header in my code.. works as a dashboard, albeit less customizability.